# Sort records on multiple columns and conditions

Tags: mysql

I have the below table, that stores the rank of person participating in respective events.

event_running and event_jumping are the events and the ranks stored.

```
CREATE TABLE `ranks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `personid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `event_running` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_longjump` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Sample data

```
INSERT INTO `ranks` (`id`, `personid`, `event_running`, `event_longjump`) VALUES
(1, 1, 4, 8),
(2, 2, 10, 6),
(3, 3, 5, 0),
(4, 5, 20, 1),
(5, 4, 9, 3),
(6, 6, 1, 2);
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1db88/1)

I want to build a leaderboard as below

```
| Standing | PersonID | RunningRank | JumpingRank |
|     1    |     6    |      1      |       2     |
|     2    |     4    |      9      |       3     |
|     3    |     1    |      4      |       8     |
|     4    |     3    |      5      |       0     |
|     5    |     2    |      10     |       6     |
```

This has to be sorted in ascending order - irrespective of the events lowest come first and also ranks above 20 are ignored.

And inputs on how can this be done?

Comment: What is a ranking `0` ? something like *did not finish* ?

Comment: Why has `PersonID` 4 a better ranking than 1 ? Same question for 3 and 2

Comment: Where is person #5?

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ *"ranks above 20 are ignored"*

Comment: @Cid rank 0 would be someone who never participated, PersonID 4 has a Jumping rank of 3 so he got a better rank

Comment: How would you order someone who has a running rank 9 and jumping 3 against someone who has running 3 and jumping 9 ?

Comment: Yes, didn't think about that, maybe one after the other in any order.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something similar to below

```
select PersonID,
       RunningRank,
       JumpingRank,
       (RunningRank + JumpingRank) as Total
from ranks
order by Total asc
limit 20;
```

Comment: that's straight, let me try with the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.

```
set @row_number = 0; 

select  (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) as standing, personid, event_running, event_longjump from ranks
where event_running < 20 and event_longjump < 20
order by 
    case when if(event_longjump=0,event_running ,event_longjump) < event_running
         then event_longjump else event_running end
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=Bu3v38vtcj)

Answer (score 0):

Your sorting criteria is a bit vague. I am assuming that you want to sort on the basis of cumulative of the ranks across all events and its jumping score.

**Also, please explain the position of person Id 3 in your queation**.
You can do,

```
select PersonID,
       RunningRank,
       JumpingRank,
       (JumpingRank + RunningRank) as cumulativeRank
from ranks
ORDER BY cumulativeRank, JumpingRank aesc
limit 20;
```

This will get you all the positions baring person id 3

Comment: That's a neat idea, let me check with the actual data

Comment: Please explain me about the person id 3. According to the comments on the question, you chose id 4 over id1 because its jumping rank was low. So you will be sorting against jumping rank also. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the cumulative ranking would not work, in case of JumpingRank:1 and RunningRank:19 this person would not come on top of the leader board.

Comment: it will work.. but I am sure about the sorting creteria you are using.... Is my above explaination is correct?